# jQuery inline script not working in Firefox 4

Tags: jquery, firefox4

I downloaded Firefox 4 today, and realized my site does not work as expected. As I looked for answers over the internet, I found solutions that called for adding the inline script by way of

`document.write('<script src="path/js/inlineScript.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>')`.

I copied and pasted all of my inline code to an external file, and this is how I am adding the inline script now (working in all browsers, and partially in firefox 4): from comments inquiry regarding the markup, I here is the link: http://filetaxes4free.com/temporary/index.php

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    document.write('
        <script src="path/js/inlineScript.js" 
                type="text/javascript">
        <\/script>'
    );

</script>
```

I am using  jQuery 1.6.1, jQuery tabs (in code you can see they are set to rotate and fadein/fadeout through opacity toggle) Some of the jQuery is working and some is not; the change of the file name when event mouseover and mouseout is not working, and the animation on when event mouseover and mouseout is not working either (this is the content of inlineScript.js file)

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs().tabs({  
        fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 1000 }}
    ).tabs('rotate', 3500, false);

    jQuery("ul#frontModule li a img").live('mouseover mouseout', function() {

        var fileName = jQuery(this).attr('src').search("-active");

        if (event.type == 'mouseover' && fileName == -1 ) {
            jQuery(this).attr("src", jQuery(this).attr("src")
                .replace(".png","-active.png"));
        }
        else {
            jQuery(this).attr("src", jQuery(this).attr("src")
                .replace("-active.png",".png"));
        }
    });

    /* LOGO anitmated text*/

    jQuery( "#logo" ).airport(
        [ 'small business web design', 
            'online marketing', 
            'search engine optimization', 
            'websonalized-com']
    );

    //menu animation

    jQuery('#rightBody .menu li a').live('mouseover mouseout', function(){

        if ( event.type == 'mouseover' ) 
            jQuery(this).animate({ marginLeft: "15px" }, 500 );
        else 
            jQuery(this).animate({marginLeft: "0" }, 500 );
    });

    //css for IE css3pie.com
    if (window.PIE) {

        //jQuery('.rounded').each(function() {
            //PIE.attach(this);
        //});

        jQuery('.roundRightEI').each(function() {
            PIE.attach(this);
        });

    }//end IE scripts
});
```

What changes do I need to make to make for this script to work in Firefox 4

Comment: What's the HTML markup? Did you try running a code with Firebug console on?

Comment: @AR The script works in all other browsers; what do you mean by "What's the HTML markup?"

Comment: I mean the actual page markup with the content that needs to be manipulated by Jquery.

Comment: @ Cold Hawaiian http://hsivonen.iki.fi/script-execution/

Comment: @AR, OK, the website was in my computer (XAMPP) and now I have it in a public host. This is the link: http://filetaxes4free.com/temporary/index.php

Comment: @IberoMedia:  So I'm wondering why just using `<script src="path/js/inlineScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` doesn't work?

Comment: @Sparky672 , part of inlineScript.js is working. That is how the rotation of tabs gets set. In firefox 4 I see the tabs rotating. But as I said before, the mouseover mouseout are the ones not working

Comment: @IberoMedia:  I think I understand your question... I just don't understand how,  `document.write('<script src="path/js/inlineScript.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>')` is supposed to solve it.  Perhaps mentioning some background details on **why** this was a suggested solution would have alleviated my confusion.

Comment: @Skparky672 From what I've read over the internet in possible solutions, FireFox 4 has implemented HTML 5 engine, strict, and from previous versions to version 4, there's been a change in the order in which the scripts load and run. This pages introduces us to the process: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/script-execution/ and proposes the solution I had implemented.

Comment: Well in Firebug on FF4 I can see errors in console in PIE.js and inlineScript.js but it seems that error in inlineScript is cause by PIE.js error (PIE.attach is not a function
[Break On This Error] PIE.attach(this); ) I do use PIE myself, but not the .js version, I have the file on server and list path to it in css. Maybe you should try removing PIE.js to see if it's gonna work.

Comment: @AR I removed and the errors are gone (I saw the errors before) but the jQuery still partially working :(

Comment: well there's event is not defined error. And there are so many attached js files - I've never seen anything like that. It's super heavy and super slow. And all the different css files. It just a brutal overload.

Comment: @AR DUDE YOU GOT IT!!! I defined the code should be ....live('mouseover mouseout', function(event).... noticed the event word inside the parentheses Thank you for pointing out there was still one error. I checked again, and searched for and found the solution inhouse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857538/jquery-event-not-defined-on-mouseover-mouseout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually all I needed to do was to add the word "event" when calling the callback from the event.

Old code:

```
 jQuery('#rightBody .menu li a').live('mouseover mouseout', function(){

        if ( event.type == 'mouseover' ) 
            jQuery(this).animate({ marginLeft: "15px" }, 500 );
        else 
            jQuery(this).animate({marginLeft: "0" }, 500 );
    });
```

New code:

```
 jQuery('#rightBody .menu li a').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event){

        if ( event.type == 'mouseover' ) 
            jQuery(this).animate({ marginLeft: "15px" }, 500 );
        else 
            jQuery(this).animate({marginLeft: "0" }, 500 );
    });
```

Something having to do with HTML5 and strict standards

Answer (score 0):

Try including your script in the following way and see if that makes any difference.

```
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='path/js/inlineScript.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
```

Sometimes quotes within your scripts may interfere with quotes included in the declaration responsible for the loading.

Comment: I'm wondering why one would have to load the Includes in this way.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm just taking a stab with this suggestion, but unescaping the document.write method ensures that the content of your script is not confused with HTML or special characters. In particular (and I'm quoting here), it means the code will work in XML / XHTML and HTML without having to mess with CDATA.

Comment: I thought maybe that was the case.  I asked the OP to explain more about why that was a suggested solution.  It seems odd that everything was working until FF 4 and that rewriting the Includes is the solution.  I'm confused by this line of thinking and wanted to know the logic behind the original suggestion.